# What are the benefits of transformational over transactional leadership?

Tags: leadership, io-psychology

[Transformational leadership](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformational_leadership) is sometimes recommended as a way of motivating and inspiring followers in contrast to more [transactional styles of leadership](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_leadership).

There is a large pop-psych literature on leadership, but I'm specifically interested in scientifically rigorous empirical evidence supporting or not supporting the value of transformational leadership.

- What is the empirical support for transformational leadership?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one meta analytic comparison:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15506858

Bernard M. Bass is one of the most cited researchers on this field:
Here is one of his articles but there are plenty on the net:

http://www.apa.org/pubs/journals/releases/apl-882207.pdf

I think he is also author of MLQ - multifaceted survey of leadership.

There is also revised theory by Bass and Avolio:
The implications of transactional and transformational leadership.

And also: Re-examining the components of transformational and transactional leadership using the Multi-factor Leadership; Journal of Occupational and organizational psychology. 2010.

Comment: Can you elaborate or summarize these articles? Otherwise this answer is too vague.

Comment: Yes. Transformational leadership is overrated IMO. New findings shows that different situations need different leadership styles. There are plenyty of books/articles on this theme if was trying to be concise to answer 'empirical support'.